# IE <video> tag src error, why does this happen?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, video, internet-explorer-10

I have the following basic video tag in a page:

```
<video src="media/pop.mp4" width="698" height="392" preload="none" controls autoplay>
```

This is a cshtml page in a MVC4 web app.  When I build and run using localhost in IE10 it works - the video plays.

When I publish to the website, the video gives me an 'invalid source' error in IE10 and doesn't play.  It plays fine in Chrome from the website.

Where would IE be looking for the file given that it plays fine in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You should check what mimetype the webserver is trying to use when serving .mp4 files.  Perhaps chrome ignores it, while IE 10 requires the correct mimetype.

Comment: I checked the mimetype on the server and video/mp4 is there.  I actually got IE to play the video, but had to replace the media/pop.mp4 with the full path.  So there is a solution, but I would still like to know why the above path works in Chrome but not IE.